# ${\rm dist}_A (x)= \inf\limits_{y\in A}\|y-x\|$ is continuous in the weak topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

For which Banach spaces $X$ the function ${\rm dist}_A (x)=\inf\limits_{y\in A} \| y-x\| $ is weak continuous for all weakly closed subsets of $X$ ?

Can anyone give me any suggestion ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the finite-dimensional ones.

Suppose that the assumption holds in a Banach space $X$. Now the weak topology on $X$ is Hausdorff, so in particular the distance function is continuous for $A = \{0\}$. In other words, the norm map $x \mapsto ||x||$ is weakly continuous. Thus the open ball $B(0,1)$, which is the inverse image of $]-1,1[$, is weakly open in $X$. But in an infinite-dimensional space weakly open sets are unbounded, so $X$ must be finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is: For all Banach spaces for which the weak topology coincides with the norm topology. That is, e.g., for $\ell^1$ (Schur's Theorem) but not for all other $\ell^p$, $1 < p \le \infty$.

Comment: The weak topology coincides with the norm topology if and only if the space is finite dimensional.

Comment: @spin: You are right. I *tried* to answer the different question about "sequential continuity"...